# datatables serverside refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatable

Используется `DataTables 1.10.15` для работы с таблицами. Данные загружаются с использованием `"ajax": "server_processing.php"` . Как можно обновить данные в таблице после их изменения? `$('#table_data').ajax.reload()` не отрабатывает.

```
$('#table_data').DataTable( {
    "processing": true,
    "serverSide": true,
    "order": [[ 0, "desc" ]],
    "ajax": "server_processing.php?forpage=datawork&table_name=<?php echo $_GET["table_name"];?>"
});
```

Comment: А почему не работает? Что пишет?

Comment: @ThisMan в консоли ошибок нет. Просто не отрабатывает.

Comment: А если так `$('#table_data').dataTable( ).api().ajax.reload();`

Answer (score 0):

> $('#table_data').ajax.reload()

Вы забыли про сам плагин, попробуйте вот так

```
$('#table_data').DataTable().ajax.reload()
```

Comment: var table = $('#table_data').DataTable();
var oTable = $('#table_data').dataTable(); оба варианта не работают

Comment: @Дмитрий значит вы что-то не правильно делаете, потому что на офф сайте это пример работает, добавьте в вопрос тогда полный код загрузки/инициализации табилцы

Comment: добавил в вопрос инициализацию ( данные загружаются корректно )

Answer (score 0):

Бяда оказалась в том что надо было немного подождать перед обновлением таблицы. И тогда xhr нормально приходит и всё работает.

```
setTimeout(function(){$('#table_data').DataTable().ajax.reload(null, false);}, 1000);
```

null - callback функции который вызывается при обновлении таблицы

false - пользователь остаётся на той же странице в таблице где и был. Если поставить true - уйдёт на 1 страницу с стандартным количеством записей.